# Using notepad++ to find and replace text using wildcard

Tags: regex

Hello I am trying to find and replace text in notepad++ using a wildcard to replace whats inside quotes.  For example I need to be able to find `<a href="http://example.com/wp-content/2014/09/08/hello-world.jpg">` and replace with `<a href="http://example.com/2014/09/08/hello-world/1/">`.  I tried `<a href=" * ">` but it says nothing can be found..

Can someone help me figure it out..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression looks for a space character "zero or more" times and a trailing space. If you want to replace the entire contents between the quotations, capture the first and last portion of the tag and replace only the middle.

```
Find: (<a href=")[^"]*(">)
Replace: \1replacement\2
```

This regular expressions says:

```
(            # group and capture to \1:
 <a href="   #   '<a href="'
)            # end of \1
 [^"]*       #   any character except: '"' (0 or more times)
(            # group and capture to \2:
 ">          #   '">'
)            # end of \2
```